# Is running a dockerfile (through docker compose) in GitHub workflows WITHOUT a license allowed

Tags: docker, github, docker-compose, dockerfile, github-actions

Obligatory "I've never used docker in production and this is my first proper go at it beyond hello world".

I'm a consultant working for a client who has so far refused to get docker licenses. We would like to take advantage of docker such that we can improve our integration tests (having a SQL Server instance running in a container). Our build pipelines run on GitHub workflows. Are we allowed to `docker-compose up --build` on GitHub's own ubuntu-latest runners, without being in violation of the license? I am well aware that for devs to run this locally, they would need docker desktop, which does need a license. We are getting around that requirement by either using Podman, or just having the devs locally run the integration tests against their localdb.

Comment: Your developers are free to run docker (and `docker compose`) without a license. The license is only required for Docker Desktop. Since you're not interacting with Docker Desktop in your GitHub workflows, you don't need to worry about licensing. See also <https://www.docker.com/pricing/faq/>.